# Moving between multiple Activities

Tags: android

I am trying to figure the best way to control 'sets' of Activities deployed from an initial 'launch' Activity.

```
A>B(Launches either C1, C2 or C3)

>C1>D1>E1>F1 ... etc

>C2>D2>E2>F2 ... etc

>C3>D3>E3>F3 ... etc
```

I require the behaviour whereby a 'home' button is available on all x1, x2 and x3 Activities. When this 'home' button is pressed on a Cx Activity, it takes the user back to B, however if pressed on either Dx, Ex, Fx etc Activity, it takes them back to the Cx Activity.

If I make my C Activity declarations SingleTop, how can I make them unique (in terms of Intents) from the subsequent D, E, F etc. Activities?

Answer (score 3):

suppose at this time your activity stack is this

```
{c > d > e > f}
```

f is top order activity if you just want to bring up  front the activity c then you should use the IntentFlag
`intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)}`

 and if you want to also clear activity that in stack which above the activity c then you should use IntentFlag

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: But what do I launch 'C' (proposed 'home' screen) as in the first place? NewTask?